# Is it possible to org-bable-tangle an org file from the command line?

Tags: org-babel

I would like to manage the tangling my org files with a Makefile. Though I can not find any information of how to tangle files from the command line.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
emacs --batch --eval "(require 'org)" --eval '(org-babel-tangle-file "file-to-tangle.org")'
```

(That shell quoting is meant for Bash, adjust if you use a different shell.)

EDIT: Thanks to @SkydiveMike for pointing out I had mistakenly written `org-babel-tangle` instead of `org-babel-tangle-file`.

Comment: I tried it and received a `Wrong type argument: stringp, nil` error message, any suggestion of what I am possibly doing wrong?

Comment: I also need the `-L` flag to add the current directory to the load path, and `-l file-to-tangle.org` to load the file before attempting to tangle it.

Comment: `emacs --batch -l org foo.org -f org-babel-tangle` or `emacs --batch -l org --eval '(org-babel-tangle-file "foo.org")'` works for me.

Comment: Thanks @xuchunyang, I am using your suggestion and it is working perfect.

Comment: With this method blocks in subtrees that are commented out with `C-c ;` are
not ignored.

Comment: For a Bash script, this is useful: `emacs --batch -l org --eval "(org-babel-tangle-file \"$1\")"`

Comment: For completeness, the solution by xuchunyang works (as compared to the original) because it has org-babel-tangle-file (which accepts a FILE argument) as compared to org-babel-tangle which works on the current buffer.

Comment: @Omar I'm getting prompted for comment syntax `No comment syntax is defined.  Use: ` which I know is because of some vimscript and lua I have in configs.org. The solution is to install vimrc-mode and lua-mode, which I have installed. If I tangle from within Emacs with `M-x org-babel-tangle` while visiting configs.org it works without the prompt. Any idea how to get rid of the prompt when running the terminal command?